# Google App Engine phpBB

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpbb

I was wondering whether it's possible to install a phpbb instance to Google App Engine since I saw this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/ and this: http://php-apps.appspot.com/

Comment: The work-around overhead is way higher to use phpbb because first of all there is no direct language support and again there is no direct remote FTP support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Standing up a phpBB instance on Google App Engine and Cloud SQL](http://fredsa.allen-sauer.com/2013/07/standing-up-phpbb-instance-on-google.html).

They seem to have done it. I am trying to look for a Youtube tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I am not that expert but as far as I know GAE is not natively designed for PHP.

You can definitely use this instruction as a basis on [How to Add phpBB](http://jelastic.com/ru/docs/phpbb)   with Jelastic service. The given instruction seems to present a pretty easy start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible -- see: http://fredsa.allen-sauer.com/2013/07/standing-up-phpbb-instance-on-google.html

(App Engine now has a PHP runtime: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. It's hard to say. It's possible to run SQL as well as PHP via Quercus (JVM). The limitations you'll run into are if phpBB depends on any specific behavior that App Engine does not support, such as native filesystem access. I haven't heard of anyone trying phpBB on GAE before, so if you took a shot at it, you'd be blazing a trail!

Comment: Hmm... I already found bitnami+amazon ec2 is an easy way to rollout phpbb3 fast and for free (free tier). If I've got some time I'll try because app engine is nice and in my opinion fast in responsiveness.